# Вставка ссылок в запись wordpress, проблема с изображением статьи (записи) при вставке

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

У меня такая проблема. Я пытаюсь вставить в запись ссылку на другую запись своего блога, но картинка не подгружается, в чём может быть проблема? Seo настроено, og теги тоже, при копипасте ссылки в мессенджеры или соц сети всё работает корректно, но при встраивании в запись изображение не подгружается. Использую плагин The SEO Framework для сео, поддержка oembed там включена.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой плагин у вас используется?

Comment: для встраивания ссылок никакой, это стандартный gutenberg редактор, для сео - 
The SEO Framework